# Spark streaming maintain kafka offset periodically as it processes

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka, offset

In spark streaming direct-approach from kafka, there is a way by which I can know the kafka offset level ranges. However if I would like periodically maintain offset level so that if needed I can reprocess items from a offset. Is there any way I can retrieve offset of a message in rdd while I am processing each message?
E.g. With offsetranges, I have start and end offset for the RDD,
but what if while processing each record of the RDD system encounters and error and job ends. Now if I want to begin processing from the record that failed, how do I first save the last successful offset so that I can start with that when starting next time.

Answer (score 0):

With Spark 1.3 released there is a new [direct approach (no receiver)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers) that hides this low-level complexity behind the scenes. In case of a failure and sufficient Kafka retention messages can be recovered from Kafka automatically after restart.

Comment: Well I was looking to a capability where in I would be able to store kafka offset externally on periodic basis as I process messages. This way I know if there is any data that I want to reprocess from 1AM two days back, I would have some offset to start from, since I will be storing the offset periodically.